# PropertyChange not fire on Reading Panel when I reply or forward email on Office 2013

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook, add-in

I am using Add-in Express(v 7.6.4084) to create an Outlook plugin. 
The problem is, that the MailItem.PropertyChange isn't triggered when reply an email on reading panel.
I have searched several topics but wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are talking about the inline response feature. If so, you need to use the [ActiveInlineResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj231535(v=office.15).aspx) property to get an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane. It fires the PropertyChange event as expected on my PC with Outlook 2013 installed.

Note, you need to declare the source object at the global scope to prevent it from being swiped by the garbage collector.

Comment: Hi Astafiev, thanks for new approach. I have try as follow but not success: http://imgur.com/5TpAw7E Please review help me. @eugene-astafiev

Comment: Declare the source object at the class level. As soon as the method ends the GC may swipe the heap and destroy the source object. So, you will never get an event.

Comment: Thanks you very very much @eugene-astafiev, it worked !